# Capture online video streams for image processing

Tags: image-processing, opencv, video-streaming

I am trying to capture online streamed content process them image by image. I have the API's written for images in openCV in python 2.7 I am just trying to extend this and see explore different possibilities (and ofcourse choose the best method) for capturing and processing these online video streams. Can this be done in openCV? If not(or simpler) any other alternative (python alternative highly preferred)?

Thanks
Ajay

Comment: OpenCV is best suited for real time image processing...you can use OpenCV with C/C++ also...other libraries like ITK are also there...but lot depends on your application...if its real time (20 - 40 fps) OpenCV is best suited...C/C++ will add advantage as its a compiled language (Python I presume is an interpreted language...correct me if I am wrong coz I know very less about python)...however some APIs which python uses for OpenCV are nothing but wrappers around C/C++ code...so performance is not an issue as such...lot depends on your application..

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is openCV capable of capturing online video streams?